# Styling an autofill suggestion

Tags: css, google-chrome

Pretty simple: I'm working on the CSS of inputs, but when Chrome (on MacOS) fills the input with a suggestion (autofill feature), it changes the font. Is there a way to override this to keep my custom font and the rest of the CSS properties?

The most disturbing is the fact that the field changes its height, this is really ugly...

Maybe I searched with the wrong keywords, but I didn't find anything...

Here is a quick sample to reproduce it with an email field, I hope you'll have suggestions in your browser:

```css
input#email {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: "Krub";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Krub&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<input id="email"></input>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you on about fixing the font change when you hover the autoselect option or when the actual autoselect option is chosen and inputted?

Comment: @KarlChelton My point is about when I hover the autoselect option: it fills the input but with the wrong font, and the worst is that the font does not have exactly the same size, so it also changes the height of the input...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The non-standard chained pseudo-classes `:-webkit-autofill:focus` can be used to style focused input elements being autofilled in Chrome.

It appears however that Chrome is ignoring some properties affected to `:-webkit-autofill:focus`, such as `color` and `font-family`. The color of the text can be changed through the (non-standard) property `-webkit-text-fill-color`, but there is no other property that can be used to change the font of the text.

A solution could have been to use JavaScript to copy the hovered suggestion, append it to a new element, place that element on top of the input and style it as you want. This is not possible though, as the suggestions are not injected as input value, and the content of the select input added by Chrome is not accessible either (probably both for security reasons).

You can however mitigate the issue by either:

- preventing Chrome from autocompleting by setting `autocomplete="off"` on the input element;
- setting height and width to the input to prevent it from changing size as the user hovers suggestions.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That helps, thank you for your answer! I can't turn off the autocomplete, I'm pretty sure users won't like that. I'll probably end up setting the height of my inputs and this will be all :)

Answer (score 7):

As of now it seems that there's no way to change this in Chrome. I'd definitely call it a bug.

However, a decent workaround is to set the `font-family` for all autofill-able inputs or inputs within forms that have autofill abilities to this:

`font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;`

This is a great cross-browser, cross-platform solution because it just takes whatever your system font is, which is exactly what Chrome seems to be doing for it's autofill font.

It also ensures that your forms are going to have readable fonts on whatever OS your user is using.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about [changing the autofill styling](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/) in CSS Tricks blog.

Essentially, adding the following snippet will allow you to change the font. You can also add any other styling here, as seen in [this CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/oxyJxR).

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    font-family: Times;
}
```

Comment: Sorry mate, but this does not work. On your codepen link, ok, the background is black and the text is green, but the font is changing. Maybe this is something specific on MacOS, but Chrome adds its own style when I hover a suggestion and the field does not keep my style :(

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the Chrome auto-fill text is forced to be `10pt, sans-serif`.  So if you style your input box the same, it won't visibly change when the page is clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working solution that worked for me:

```css
input#email {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: "Krub";
  color: blue;
}

input:-webkit-autofill::first-line {
      color: red;
      font-size: 2rem;
      font-family: "Krub"; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Krub&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<input id="email"></input>
```

Also I noticed that for some reason `display: flex` conflicts with that code, take a look:

```css
input#email {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: "Krub";
  color: blue;
  display: flex;
}

input:-webkit-autofill::first-line {
      color: red;
      font-size: 2rem;
      font-family: "Krub"; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Krub&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<input id="email"></input>
```