# How to override default styles when selecting from default autocomplete values in an HTML5 input?

Tags: html, css, forms

It's been a long while since I've dealt with this, and today it seems there are a few quirks across browsers. How do you remove all the styles when you are selecting an autocomplete result from an `<input type="email" />`?

In **Safari** it looks like this (note: I don't have any yellow or green styles in my app):

[image]

In **Chrome** it looks like this (has blue and uses a font I don't have specified in my CSS, notice how the text is small and unstyled before fully selecting it):

[image]

How do I control all these styles? I would like for it to just be white in all cases for now (background white), and the text to be the same style in all states (placeholder is slightly lighter gray text, but that's it).

I tried styling `input:focus::placeholder {}` but that doesn't seem to do anything related to these things that are happening. I tried `input:active` which is what I would think is the state when selecting an autocomplete value, but no go. Any ideas?

Here is my complete input if that makes a difference:

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" required="" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="Your best email" style="min-width: 100%;" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="0">
```

I don't know where `data-gtm-form-interact-field-id` is coming from, that is what I get when copying outerHTML from the web inspector.

#### Update

As per @Qyriad's `:autofill` suggesion, I got this far:

```
input:-internal-autofill-selected {
  appearance: menulist-button;
  background-image: none !important;
  background-color: var(--color-base-background) !important;
  color: fieldtext !important;
}

input:-webkit-autofill::first-line {
  background: var(--color-base-background);
  font-family: 'Noto Sans Mono';
  font-size: 16px;
}

input:auto-fill {
  background: var(--color-base-background);
  font-family: 'Noto Sans Mono';
  font-size: 16px;
}

input:-webkit-autofill {
  background: var(--color-base-background);
  font-family: 'Noto Sans Mono';
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

[image]

But still the font style isn't working... Appears to be a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271193/styling-an-autofill-suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [`:autofill` CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:autofill).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Comment: Does the demo in the linked Mozilla documentation work?

Comment: No, I got closer with what I updated the question with given your feedback though, maybe it's not possible to fully style it.

Comment: You may want to try !important on all of the styles. If that still doesn't work, the browsers may just not support it after all.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code to customize the appearance of autofill inputs, including
the background and border colors

```
/* Works for Chrome, Edge, and Safari */
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
  /* Transitions the background color over 5000s */
  transition: background-color 5000s;
  /* Changes text color to black */
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #000 !important;
  /* Adds a 1px black border and removes the outline */
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline:none;
}

/* Works for Firefox */
input:-moz-autofill {
  /* Changes text color to black */
  -moz-text-fill-color: #000 !important;
  /* Adds a 1px black border and removes the outline */
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline:none;
}
```